# control image loading in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an Image gallery and i want a few images to load when the next button is clicked.....
for example,

```
$("#next").css({cursor:"pointer"}).click(function(){
            //load image1,image2,image3
        });
```

HTML

```
<img src="image1.jpg"><img src="image2.jpg"><img src="image3.jpg">
```

i don't want to append them to a division, these image tags are already present in 'gallery' div tag... I just want to stop them from loading when the page loads at first and when the user clicks on next button theses images can load ...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images elements are already in your markup, and they have the `src` attribute defined, the image files will be downloaded when the page starts loading.

You should either create the image elements programmatically or leave the `src` attribute empty on your markup, and then assign it when the user clicks next.

Option 1:

```
// on the click event...
var images = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg', 'img3.jpg'],
    gallery = $('#gallery');
$.each(images, function () {
  $('<img/>').attr('src', this).appendTo(gallery);
});
```

Option 2:

Markup:

```
<img id="img1"/> <img id="img2"/> <img id="img3"/>
```

On the click event:

```
$('#img1').attr('src', 'image1.jpg');
$('#img2').attr('src', 'image2.jpg');
$('#img3').attr('src', 'image3.jpg');
```

**Edit:**

Another option comes to my mind when you talk about lazy loading.

*Option 3:*

You could remove the src attribute of your images, and store it using the [$.data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data) function, then in your click event, restore the image src to its original value, for example:

```
$(function () {
  // put a "defaultImage" on all images of gallery
  // and store the original src attribute
  $('#gallery img').each(function () {
    $(this).data('originalSrc', $(this).src).attr('src', 'defaultImage.jpg');
  });

  $("#next").click(function(){
    $('#gallery img').each(function () {
      // restore the original src attribute:
      $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('originalSrc'));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: so their is no way I can stop an image from loading if the src markup is defined... and I have to assign the src attributes when the user clicks next, if that's the case then thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Create img elements and add them to the DOM.

```
var img = $(document.createElement("img"));
img.attribute("src", "image1.jpg");
$("#mydiv").append(img);
```

Comment: i don't want to append them to a division, these image tags are already present in 'gallery' div tag... I just want to stop them from loading when the page loads at first and when the user clicks on next button theses images can load ...Thanks